# На сервере не работает простейшая Go программа

Tags: golang, build, install

Сервер Linux debian 4.9.0-4-amd64 с Apache+РНР+MySQL и go1.9.4.linux-amd64 Запускаю простейшую программу из учебника (имя  файла srv.go):

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func requestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, world")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", requestHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Компилирую: go buil srv.go запускаю ./srv и ничего... бинарник в папке есть, среди процессов (ps aux - srv) такой программы нет, в барузере http:// ip-adres:8080 - Не удалось найти веб-сайт. Код ошибки: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
При использовании  go install srv.go ситуация совершенно аналогичная...

На локальной машине все работает без проблем, а на сервере - никак. Может быть как-то не так запускаю или обращаюсь в браузере? Помогите разобраться что не так.

Comment: проверяйте на ошибки: `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))` на вскидку наверно линух будет жаловаться на порт

Comment: проверьте есть ли что то ещё на порту 8080 поменяйте на какой нибудь рандомный 8123 на пример

Comment: Поставил в код log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9001", nil)) в ps aux есть процесс, но в барузере http:// ip-adres:8080 - Не удалось найти веб-сайт. Код ошибки: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND так и осталось. Останавливал Apache, вдруг коллизия по порту... никак не повлияло.

Comment: ну если вас в коде порт `9001` то и в браузере соотвественно `http://ip-adres:9001`

Comment: Да, так и есть, ошибся в сообщении... недоглядел.

Comment: значит заработало?

Comment: Нет, увы @biosckon кроме того, что после запуска ./srv появляется в таблице процессов, дальше прогресса нет. В браузере набираю http://ip-adres:9001 - код ошибки как раньше. Сервер работает, консольные проги выполняются, а вот с этой элементарной бьюсь уже почти неделю... И никак.

Comment: для начала на самом серваке проверьте в терминале `curl localhost:9001`. и ещё когда вы пришете `ip-adres:9001` это выглядит на пример как `172.168.1.3:9001`. те. IP адрес вашего сервака правильно?

Comment: `~# curl localhost:9001` - на сервере все сработало, результат `Hello, world` вызов в браузере на локальном компе `http://ip-adres` где ip-adres выглядит типа `172.168.1.3:9001` только с адресом моего сервера - дает ошибку, как и раньше...

Comment: а ясно с вашей системой и программой все в порядке. вам нужно с адресами и фаерволом и т.д. разобраться. INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND это ваш комп не видит сервер вообще

Comment: С локального компа попытался достучаться до сервера, используя `resp, err := http.Get(http://ip-adres :9000l)
 if err != nil {
  return false, fmt.Sprintf("Ошибка соединения. %s", err)
 }` получил такую ошибку: `Get http://ip-adres :9000: dial tcp ip-adres :9000: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.` Получается, что по таймауту отваливается соединение... Так по любым портам кроме `:80`, на нем `Онлайн. http-статус: 200`

Comment: проверяйте настройки файрвола на вашем серваке. это даже очень хорошо что вас сервер по умолчанию блокирует все.

Comment: Да, @biosckon вы были совершенно правы. Как только админ пробросил нужные порты и открыл их - все сразу заработало.

Comment: Отлично :). 